# Grouping Android notifications with Prime31's etcetera android plugin

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, notifications, prime31

I am having difficulties setting up group notifications with this etcetera Unity plugin. I have notifications being scheduled using the

> int scheduleNotification( AndroidNotificationConfiguration config )

function but I can't seem to group them. I understand that one notification needs to be used as the summary notification, but I don't understand what to use for the `GroupKey`.

Can the `GroupKey` be anything?

Can someone show me example code that groups a few notifications together?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this working? I'm stuck with the same issue. Using the same groupKey for all notifications and assigning the first notification in the group with isGroupSummary = true. However, nothing is working... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

So the etceterplugin uses the function call notificationBuilder instead of notificationclCompatBuilder. Thus for android firmware versions 4.1-4.3 (it's been a while since i looked at this issue.) The grouping of notifications is not compatible. The support from etcetera did not provide any informative information and I created my own plug in.

I provided thorough questions and asked what versions they supported and they referred me to the android docs.... I suggest making your own plug in and using notificationCompatBuilder instead of notification builder.